# Excel macro to do find/replace and string value

Tags: excel, vba

As part of an end process dump of data from an application I manipulate the raw output so myself and my team can use further.

I currently manually alter this data but I have been experimenting with excel macro's to try carry out the same action.  A basic example of what I am trying to achieve is:

Sample Data

[image: Sample Data]

Create a macro to do a find and replace to remove the tags from the raw data and add to the cell value to have a final set of data like ' + Cell Value + ',

I have little experience with VBA and have put this together from snippets of code found from a few quick searches around this area.

```
Sub ReplaceMetadataTags()
    Columns("A").Replace    What:="<tag1>", _
                            Replacement:="", _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            MatchCase:=False, _
                            SearchFormat:=False, _
                            ReplaceFormat:=False

    Columns("A").Replace    What:="</tag1>", _
                            Replacement:="", _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            MatchCase:=False, _
                            SearchFormat:=False, _
                            ReplaceFormat:=False

    Dim myCell As Range
    For Each myCell In Selection
        If myCell.Value <> "" Then
            myCell.Value = Chr(39) & Chr(39) & myCell.Value & Chr(39)
        End If
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

But lack the experience to debug this further.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: You can do it only using excel formula. No need `VBA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ReplaceTags()

    With Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns("B")

        .Replace "<*>", "''"   'replaces "<Tag>" and "</Tag>"

        .Replace "''", "',"

    End With

End Sub
```

---

Sample

[image: Result]

Comment: I like your approach, but, since the `tag`s may not always have that name, suggest you replace that word with a wild card:  ` .Replace "<*>"` and ` .Replace "</*>"`

Comment: Much better suggestion @RonRosenfeld, since I was thinking of creating a list of tags and looping over them for replacements - thanks

Answer (score 1):

**1) Code:**

You could try, very fast method using array:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RemoveTags()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim arr()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")       'Change as required
        arr = Intersect(.Range("A:A"), .UsedRange).Value
        Dim i As Long

        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            If Not IsEmpty(arr(i, 1)) Then
                On Error Resume Next
                arr(i, 1) = Chr$(39) & Chr$(39) & Split(Split(arr(i, 1), ">")(1), "<")(0) & Chr$(39) & ","
                On Error GoTo 0
        Next i

        .UsedRange.Columns("B") = arr
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Note:**

1. Put  `.UsedRange.Columns("A") = arr`   If you want in place replacement rather than column B.
2. Using typed function Chr$ is significantly faster than Chr
3. Using  `.UsedRange` can lead to unexpected results so you may want to be explicit in the range to work with e.g. arr = .Range("A1:A15").Value
4. Some basic error handling with `If Not IsEmpty` and On Error Resume Next in case search terms not present.

**2) Formula example:**

With formula, can't do in cell replacement, but only need one Chr(39), in fact CHAR(39), to display the "'" visibly in the cell. In B1:

```
 =CHAR(39)&MID(A1,FIND(">",A1,1)+1,LEN(A1)-FIND(">",A1,1)-(LEN(A1)-(FIND("<",A1,FIND(">",A1,1)+1)))-1)&CHAR(39)&","
```

**Note:**

You can swop `FIND` for `SEARCH` in the above. `FIND` is case-sensitive.  `SEARCH` is case-insensitive and can include wildcards. Doesn't matter in this context but worth being aware of. You might wrap whole thing in `IFERROR` to suppress errors if search string not found.

**Edit:**

Considering error handling it might be simpler to go with `.Replace`, as per @Paul Bica's answer, credit to him please on that, as less coding.